# Oracle APEX icons list

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

Where can I find a list of oracle icons - t-Icons and a-Icons. I searched everywhere but cannot find a complete list. I have found a few icons here and there but they do not seem to work in certain setups. I have used Font Awesome icons but they do not show up when used with t-Icon class or a-Icon class

I have tried:

```
 <span class="a-Icon icon-app-status"></span>
```

and

```
 <span class="t-Icon icon-app-status"></span>
```

and

```
 <span class="a-Icon fa-clock-o"></span>
```

but nothing shows up.

Meanwhile this worked:

although it is not the icon I wanted.

also worked. I wanted to get a list of icons that work with a-Icon or t-Icon in a span

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:icons

Comment: those did not work for me:(

Comment: Should works, if the apex version is 5.1. Do you have any component with an icon generated by apex? like a menu with an icon? check (inspect) the span icon to see what the apex is doing. In the link above, the span is: <span class="t-Icon fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting" aria-hidden="true"></span>. every span needs "t-Icon fa " + your icon class.

Comment: Thanks you! adding `t-Icon fa` did the trick

Comment: could you pout it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should works, if the apex version is 5.1. Do you have any component with an icon generated by apex? like a menu with an icon? check (inspect) the span icon to see what the apex is doing. In the link above, the span is: . every span needs "t-Icon fa " + your icon class.

Thx

Comment: how can I get advantage of this application that you put it'a URL above. 
this:
apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:icons

I want to list all apex icons in one of my pages.